# Polynomials in specified rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/compute-in-a-polynomial-ring/

I am working on this problem, and I understand what to do when the R is just the integers. However, I am not too sure how to get p(x) and q(x) when R is z/2z and z/3z. I understand that 3x, for example, is 0 in z/3z. A simple explanation would be much helpful. I am relatively new to ring theory.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You just have to simplify the polynomials  mod $2$ or mod $3$ first, remembering that, in the first case, an odd coefficient  is $1$, an even is $0$ and furthermore, $-1=1$.

Next you compute the sum and the product in the ordinary way, reducing the coefficients mod $2$ or mod $3$, e.g. in $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$, $\;2x^3\cdot 2x^2= 4x^5\equiv x^5$.